# Performance - Redrawing a new canvas or changing its css position?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starting to experiment with game development in Javascript and I just have one question before going further in the subject.

Is it more efficient (performance wise) to draw a new canvas every frame or just change the CSS `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` properties?

An example with ping pong ball in a game:

This code would be called more than 60 times per second, let's assume we have not only one ball, but more players, may be in a more complex game, more environment entities whose position need to be also updated, etc.

```
//Draws a NEW square in a NEW location that has been
//previously updated by a game method
canvasContext.fillRect(posX, posY, ballW, ballH);
```

or

```
//ball is an stand alone canvas

//Updates the position
ball.style.left = previousPos + 1;
```

Comment: "*This code would be called more than 60 times per second*" That's a rather unnecessarily high frequency don't you think?

Comment: @Popnoodles games can have a configurable Refresh Frecuency, for people with screens with more than 60Hz :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is either rendering it all yourself on one canvas or using multiple balls and modifying their [`transform` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

It's faster to use transform than `top` and `left`. You can do this:

```js
function updatePos() {
  var e = document.getElementsByClassName('ellipse');
  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    e[i].dataset.x = (parseFloat(e[i].dataset.x) || 0) + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    e[i].dataset.y = (parseFloat(e[i].dataset.y) || 0) + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
    e[i].style.transform = 'translate(' + e[i].dataset.x + 'px, ' + e[i].dataset.y + 'px)';
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(updatePos);
}
updatePos();
```

```css
.ellipse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div><div class="ellipse"></div>
```

Essentially, you just fix the `top` and `left` positions and modify the `transform`.

Comment: Awesome explanation and demo. But I didn't understand the part where you said 'he best way is either rendering it all yourself on one canvas' What did you mean?

Comment: @JuanBonnett You can do the same with a canvas and then rendering a bunch of ellipses (or whatever object) with the canvas context. That method should also be pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks, I will be using the transform method then, instead of re-drawing everything again per requestAnimationFrame() call.